# Laravel default authentication login request

Tags: laravel, authentication, postman, laravel-authentication

I would like to ask about Laravel authentication that is generated using the command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

So if my application has the name "Myapp", and I want to make a request for a login using Postman and i'm developing the app on a local server on my pc, my request should go to the following route:

http://localhost/Myapp/public/login using POST request. Am I right?

Also how should the request body look like? And what about the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was simple. First add ?_token= to the url so it becomes

```
http://localhost/Myapp/login?_token=xxxxxx
```

_token value is fetched from the login form, just inspect the form by doing right click on it and then inspect.

the body of the request is simple, only needs an email and a password.

Answer (score 0):

Use `php artisan serve --port=8080` to serve your application on `http://localhost:8080`.

If you are making an API, write your routes in `routes/api.php`, then your login URL will be `http://localhost:8080/api/login`.

If you will write your routes in `routes/web.php` then you need to manage the `CSRF` token for the Postman.

Comment: That's actually not my question or issue. I can run my application and can make APIs as i wish. my question is when I use Laravel 6 auth, what should my request body look like if i'm trying to login using Postman instead of the normal way through the app. Knowing that the login and the registration are generated by the comman:

php artisan make:auth